# Can't use float64 in keras with tensorflow backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In my `.keras/keras.json` file I have set `"floatx": "float64"`, but I got the following error.

`Input 'filter' of 'Conv2D' Op has type float32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'input'`

I have done some research and found a [link](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack/issues/50) saying that "You can monkey-patch tf.get_variable and add dtype=tf.float64 whenever dtype is None.", but I don't really get it, and can't fit it in my program.

My program is below (simplified version)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Can anyone give some advice about how to implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running on `cpu` or `gpu`? If `gpu` what card do you have?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I am running on `gpu` with `GTX 960m`, Thanks for the response.

Comment: Most GPU doesn't handle well float64, you should use float32 instead. And Keras is most likely to be written to use float32 as it is more efficient on GPU.

Comment: @ArnaudDeBroissia Thanks for your advice, but actually I was searching for solution to resolve the error  `could not synchronize on CUDA context: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED :: No stack trace available`, and found [this method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4425) and I wanted to give it a try.

Comment: @DavidChen have you tried using `theano` as backend instead?